# Jquery - Sliding up form labels problem

Tags: jquery, forms, label

I am not going to paste the whole script here, because it's too long! 
this is the link and the demo as well:
http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/775/Sliding-up-form-labels-with-jquery-and-CSS3

The problem i have, is that i dont know how to make it work for input:password - currently it's set to:

```
jQuery( 'input:text' ).each( function( )
```

if i put jQuery( 'input:text, input:password' ).each( function( ) script is not working anymore!

Any solution? i don't have too much javascript or jquery knowladge - thanks!

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me when I add a input[type=password]. Did you also change the CSS to include input[type=password] along with input[type=text]? Check http://jsfiddle.net/PNsN3/

Comment: thanks i test your code and it does work, so the css was the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the initial selector from: `jQuery('input:text')` to: `jQuery('input:text, input:password')` makes it work for me: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/frJjv/) (incidentally the 'zip' field is the only `input:password` that I used, but, still, it does work as expected).

This is in Firefox 4.x and Chromium 11 on Ubuntu 11.04, though I can't see why it *shouldn't* work in other browsers on other platforms.

References:

- [`input:password`](http://api.jquery.com/password-selector).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("input:password").each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

You can see it live here: http://jsfiddle.net/Uhhxf/2/

Comment: Bear in mind that `:password` by itself has to evaluate *every* element for that `type`; the [API](http://api.jquery.com/password-selector/) recommends that you supply the element type as well, to reduce the work required.